# Every click produces Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

my website React works correctly but I'm trying to fix this console error.
Every click produces this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Array.<anonymous> (content.js:7:89199)
    at c.trigger (content.js:7:81786)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:7:81253)
```

No matter where in the website.

I tried to remove components and see if it was coming from something in particular but I ended up removing the whole app.js content and it's still happening.

Any idea for what to look for?

I'm using React + Vite + Typescript + Tailwind

My main.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { AxiosInterceptor } from "./interceptors/axios.interceptor";

AxiosInterceptor();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!)!;
root.render(<App />);
```

My App.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./pages/landing/Landing";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import { PrivateRoutes, PublicRoutes } from "./models";
import { AuthGuard } from "./guards";
import { RoutesWithNotFound } from "./utilities";
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { LinkedInCallback } from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2";

const Login = lazy(() => import("./pages/login/Login"));
const Signup = lazy(() => import("./pages/signup/Signup"));
const Private = lazy(() => import("./pages/private/Private"));

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <div className="flex items-center h-screen justify-center">
          <div className="w-16 h-16 border-4 border-dashed rounded-full animate-spin border-red-600"></div>
        </div>
      }
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Sidebar />
          <RoutesWithNotFound>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={PrivateRoutes.PRIVATE} />} />
            <Route path={PublicRoutes.LANDING} element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path={PublicRoutes.LOGIN} element={<Login />} />
            <Route
              path={PublicRoutes.LINKEDIN_LOGIN}
              element={<LinkedInCallback />}
            />
            <Route
              path={PublicRoutes.LINKEDIN_REGISTER}
              element={<LinkedInCallback />}
            />
            <Route path={PublicRoutes.SIGNUP} element={<Signup />} />
            <Route element={<AuthGuard />}>
              <Route
                path={`${PrivateRoutes.PRIVATE}/*`}
                element={<Private />}
              />
            </Route>
          </RoutesWithNotFound>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The file pointed by the error is this one (last line is responsible for the error apparently)

[image]

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: It's a whole project in which no matter what I remove it still happens. Do you think that config files could be useful? I can include App.tsx too

Comment: You can look at the code referenced by that error in devtools to try and find the culprit.

Comment: I've added main, app tsx and a picture of the file pointed by the error. Is not written by me.

Comment: Like said above, it's not possible to give solution without a proper code. This usually happens if the value that you're trying to access is `undefined`. I'll advice you to check all the components and give fallback values to the variables, correct initialisation of data and check array index out of bounds too.

Answer (score 12):

The error relates to content.js.

This is a script that can interact with web pages that the browser visits (See e.g. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts)

The error occurs in Chrome only. I am using Chrome 109.0.5414.119. The cause is in an extension. Changing the setting in Chrome extension 'Typio Form Recovery' named 'Access to site' into a specific site instead of all sites or 'on click' solves the issue.

Cause of the error is not in the app code but in Chrome extension.

(Same error occurs in an Angular app at every click. The only common dependency from the list above is TypeScript. I am using TypeScript 4.9.4.)

Comment: You are a hero for posting this, I never would have figured it out otherwise and it was driving me crazy. Thank you so much!